# ENVI Mosaic Speed

Tags: performance, envi, mosaic

I have several Sentinel-1 images to mosaic.

The first mosaic is for 2 images of land area removal. The size of mosaic result is about 4.8 G, the second mosaic result is also about 4.8 G. Then to make mosaic using first and second mosaic result, however, the process is very slowly this time. About 17 hours later, the work only accomplished about 75%.

I want to know is this a normal situation?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that a 9.6 gb mosaic is actually "small", but 17 hours seems long... Did you have a look at your RAM availability during the process?

Comment: @LoBu RAM in process is not completed in occupied，is about 65%.So I don't think RAM leads to the slow process.